# Tweepy: Handle RateLimit in show_friendship()

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to see several friendships between two twitter users, and I'm using show_friendship(twitter_id_1, twitter_id_2) method from tweepy library inside a loop.

I wonder how can I handle RateLimit or using a cursor (http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/cursor_tutorial.html) with that method because after several loops it raises a RateLimitError.

This is the RateLimit Handle of search friends (people I'm following) but I can't figure out how to do the same with **show_friendship()**

```
def limit_handled(self, cursor):
    while True:
        try:
            yield cursor.next()
        except tweepy.RateLimitError:
            time.sleep(15 * 60)

 for friend in limit_handled(tweepy.Cursor(api.friends).items()):
      #stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling the API then you can specify the rate limit,
Eg:
api = tweepy.API(author, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True, retry_count=5, retry_delay=5)

then you can call any api for Twitter and it would accommodate rate limit.

So you can call show friendship normally as you would do:
api.show_friendship(source_id = friend, target_id = neighbor)